# What is this long Bar/Rod on the Boeing MH-47G?

Tags: military, helicopter, feature-identification, boeing

This [MH-47G](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing-Vertol_CH-47#/media/Datei:Special_Boat_Team_takes_flight_with_Nightstalkers_140521-A-PP158-160.jpg) has a thick, long rod at the bottom left front. What's the purpose of this thing?

Answer (score 6):

This is the **In flight refueling probe**, which can be used for refueling while the helicopter is airborne:

[image: MH-47G]
<sup>(image source: [pinterest.com](https://www.pinterest.de/pin/381539399678304889/))</sup>

It is almost 9 meters long to make sure the rotors do not hit the refueling drogue. You can see it in action in the following picture:

[image: Refueling]
<sup>(image source: [chinook-helicopter.com](http://www.chinook-helicopter.com/chinook/bag_o_gas.html))</sup>